# create an interactive table while rotating the piechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

All, Recently I had posted a question [Rotating a donut chart in javascript after it is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141152/rotating-a-donut-chart-in-javascript-after-it-is-rendered) that was answered and am currently using it in my app. But now we need to take this one step further and hook this donut spinning chart (high chart) to update/highlight the corresponding row on a table. Basically here's the layout. We have a donut chart on top that can spin (right now it spins in clockwise, ideally, it should spin in both directions) and a table at the bottom which is basically the data displayed on the donut. So now when the user rotates the donut the bottom piece of the donut should correspond and highlight the appropriate row in the table below. So potentially, if the bottom of the donut says IE7, then the row IE7 should get highlighted and so on.

I have a sample fiddle created here http://jsfiddle.net/skumar2013/hV9aw/1/ for reference. Can somebody share some ideas/samples on how to go about doing this? As always thanks for your help in advance.

```
$(function () {
    $('#mouseMoveDiv').mousemove(function () {
        var theChart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var currStartAngle = theChart.series[0].options.startAngle;
        console.log('currStartAngle: ' + currStartAngle);
        var newStartAngle = currStartAngle + 5;
        if (newStartAngle > 359) {
            newStartAngle = 5;
        }
        console.log(newStartAngle);
        theChart.series[0].update({
            startAngle: newStartAngle
        });
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            spacingTop: 50,
            spacingBottom: 50,
            spacingLeft: 50,
            spacingRight: 50,
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Interactive Pie Chart'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                center: ["50%", "50%"],
                startAngle: 90,
                animation: false,
                innerSize: '30%'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 44.2],
                ['IE7', 26.6],
                ['IE6', 20],
                ['Chrome', 3.1],
                ['Other', 5.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

    <Title>Interactive pie/donut chart</Title>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="mouseMoveDiv">
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
    </div>
    <table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>Firefox</td>
        <td>44.2%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>IE7</td>
        <td>26.6%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>IE6</td>
        <td>20%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chrome</td>
        <td>3.1%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Other</td>
        <td>5.4%</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Interesting. But weird. But interesting. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come up with working code, fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hV9aw/3/), but I'm not sure why :)

```
    var someData = theChart.series[0].data; // the pie data
    var N = someData.length;
    var closest = [10,-1];
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++){
        var center = someData[i].angle; // seems to be the center of the pie slice in radians
        var dis = Math.abs(center - 1.5795); // 1.5796 seems to be the center bottom of the pie in radians?
        if (dis < closest[0]){
            closest = [dis, i]; // find the closest slice to the bottom 
        }
    }
    // color the corresponding row
    if (closest[1] != lastHighlight){
        var someRows = $('#dataTable tr');
        someRows.eq(lastHighlight).css('backgroundColor','white');
        someRows.eq(closest[1]).css('backgroundColor','yellow');
        lastHighlight = closest[1];
    }
```

I'm making some assumptions here about highcharts calculations:

1. that `series.data[i].angle` is the angle of the pie slice in radians.
2. the angle of the bottom, center of the "donut" is π / 2 radians.  In a regular coordinate system it should be (3 * π) / 2, so not sure why highcharts orientates this way.

With these assumptions my code appears to work.

Comment: This is cool. I need to find a business case to incorporate this...somehow.

Comment: wow.. this is awesome man. Thank you so very much for looking into this and really really really appreciate you taking time and looking into this. Thanks again!!

Comment: I have one issue when one of the slices is more than 50%. When it rotates, the center calculation gets screwed up and the next highlight displays even before the new slice is at the bottom. Any ideas on how to got about addressing this issue?

Comment: @user1657861, it highlights the slice who's center is closest to the center bottom.  It works as I would expect here: http://jsfiddle.net/hV9aw/6/.  Are you saying this is not true or that it should highlight the one who's start is closest to the bottom?

Comment: Yeah I was expecting to highlight the one who's start is closest to the bottom.

Comment: Actually, now I think you are asking a different question, not which is "closest" to the bottom, but which one's start angle just passed the bottom.  I don't have time to pretty this code up but hopefully you'll get the idea:  http://jsfiddle.net/hV9aw/7/